# How to create a new column using values from existing column in a daframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like follows,

```
  a       b      c
AAAA    BBB -25488
AAAA    BBB -71364
AAAA    BBB +40632
AAAA    BBB +230015
AAAA    BBB +49284
AAAA    BBB -9239
AAAA    BBB +67887
AAAA    BBB -23350
AAAA    BBB +432591
```

The above data frame, in the end, should look like,

```
   a      b c      d 
AAAA    BBB -  25488
AAAA    BBB -  71364
AAAA    BBB +  40632
AAAA    BBB +  230015
AAAA    BBB +  49284
AAAA    BBB -  9239
AAAA    BBB +  67887
AAAA    BBB -  23350
AAAA    BBB +  432591
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Hi. We're not a free code writing service. Show an attempt. Ask a precise question.

Comment: Index(['Gene', 'PCs', 'Dis', 'V', 'F', 'D', 'G', 'H', 'F.1', 'G.1', 'F.2',
       'Z'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: 4 columns but the dataframe are little complicated it has certain rows with even nine columns

Comment: for this :AAAA BBB -25488 it ahs 3 column and and the converted daframe will have 4 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
print (df)
      a    b        c
0  AAAA  BBB   -25488
1  AAAA  BBB   -71364
2  AAAA  BBB   +40632
3  AAAA  BBB  +230015
4  AAAA  BBB   +49284
5  AAAA  BBB    -9239
6  AAAA  BBB   +67887
7  AAAA  BBB   -23350
8  AAAA  BBB  +432591

df[['c','d']] =  df.c.str.extract('([+-])(\d*)', expand=True)

print (df)
      a    b  c       d
0  AAAA  BBB  -   25488
1  AAAA  BBB  -   71364
2  AAAA  BBB  +   40632
3  AAAA  BBB  +  230015
4  AAAA  BBB  +   49284
5  AAAA  BBB  -    9239
6  AAAA  BBB  +   67887
7  AAAA  BBB  -   23350
8  AAAA  BBB  +  432591
```

Comment: Its throwing error, AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas. the datatype is object

Comment: Try cast column to string `df['c'] = df.c.astype(str)`

Comment: I did it..And now its a new error

Comment: Yes now it works but for those with positive signs its show Nan ..

Comment: df[['c','d']] =  df.c.str.extract('([+-])(\d*)', expand=True) and for Expand =True ist throwing error as  TypeError: extract() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand' .  And without expand as dataframe is not showing + sign its filling those columns with Nan

Comment: You have to update pandas to 0.18.1.